# Laravel 5.7 Apache 2.4 php 7.2 Undefined class constant 'SQLSRV_ATTR_FETCHES_NUMERIC_TYPE'

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, apache

I'm trying to configure my Laravel 5.7 in Apache 2.4 using PHP 7.2 but i'm getting the error

> Undefined class constant 'SQLSRV_ATTR_FETCHES_NUMERIC_TYPE'

I've already change de PHP version to 7.1
Put the lines 
LoadModule php7_module "C:/Apache24/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir C:/Apache24/php
on httpd.conf in apache

this is my php.ini

```
;extension=bz2
extension=curl
extension=fileinfo
extension=gd2
extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
extension=intl
extension=imap
;extension=interbase
extension=ldap
extension=mbstring
extension=exif      
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c
extension=odbc
extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
;extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop

;extension=snmp

;extension=soap
;extension=sockets
;extension=sqlite3
extension=tidy
extension=xmlrpc
extension=xsl

extension=php_sqlsrv_72_ts
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts

extension_dir = "ext"
```

These are my modules

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
imap
intl
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
odbc
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
PDO_ODBC
pdo_sqlsrv
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
sqlsrv
standard
tidy
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

When I use

> php artisan serve

works fine

**EDITED**

Seems that extensions is not been loaded.
I did phpinfo() and didn't show pdo_sqlsrv

Comment: Not sure if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53514815/php-pdo-sqlsrv-always-return-every-values-as-string helps.

Comment: What driver do you use to connect to SQL Server? And are you trying to set `PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_FETCHES_NUMERIC_TYPE` attribute?

Comment: I use php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts and and I'm setting true to SQLSRV_ATTR_FETCHES_NUMERIC_TYPE

Answer (score 0):

I have done by repeating these 3 steps on Ubuntu

1. Register the Microsoft Linux repositories and add their keys.

   ```
     curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -

     curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server-2017.list
   ```
2. Install SQL Server.

   ```
     sudo apt-get update

     sudo apt-get install mssql-server
   ```
3. Setup your SQL Server.

   ```
     sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup
   ```

For more detail

[Microsoft Guide](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/php/ubuntu/step/3.html)